# Creating a "customized" soap client in flex

Tags: apache-flex, soap, xmlhttprequest

I am working on a web-service that says it utilizes "SOAP" but upon closer inspection, it's very very different from the standard soap request/response structures i have seen everywhere else.

I was able to talk to the service with javascript (using xmlhttprequest) and parsing the result manually. Ive tried doing it with flex, but cannot replicate the headers as required (even the body content varies considerably). I would like to move this app to flex but unsure of how to implement this - are there any methods similar to xmlhttprequest?

An example of a request the service can accomodate is shown is here (ive managed to get this working via js): http://pastie.org/466214

Im pretty new to both web-services and flex and would appreciate *any and all* advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Update. I think ive found a way to do this using httpservice and dumping my own XML into the request.

Its not the best of solutions, but it seems to be working fine for now. If there is a better option, then I would appreciate your views on it.

PS. If anyone else is going this route, then [this post was helpful](http://tacfug.org/blog/index.cfm/2007/3/26/Flex--Posting-XML-without-using-mxhttpservice-) with regards to sending the raw xml using httpservice.